# Get the average samples per patient per interval year (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to do some calculations but can't think how to perform it. Let's imagine I do have a df like this:

```
 df <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~date, ~sample, ~baseline_date, ~last_date, ~FU, 
  'PD1' , '2021-10-01', "sample1",'2021-10-01', '2022-07-07', '279 days',
  'PD1' , '2021-10-07', "sample2", '2021-10-01','2022-07-07', '279 days',
  'PD2' , '2021-10-22', "sample1", '2021-10-22','2023-02-23', '489 days',
  'PD2', '2023-02-23', "sample2", '2021-10-22', '2023-02-23', '489 days')

ID      date           sample  baseline_date last_date  FU      
 
PD1    2021-10-01    sample1   2021-10-01    2022-07-07 279 days
PD1    2021-10-07    sample2   2021-10-01    2022-07-07 279 days
PD2    2021-10-22    sample1   2021-10-22    2023-02-23 489 days
PD2    2023-02-23    sample2   2021-10-22    2023-02-23 489 days
```

What I would like to get is the average number of samples for patients in their first 12 months, second 12 months etc... But I can't think in a smart way of doing it, any suggestions or approach about this?
Thank you

Comment: So what's the desired output for this sample input? Does the ID represent a patient? Is a "sample" just a row of the table? Is baseline date always the "first" date? Do you just want one over all "average"?

Comment: The desired output is to get the average samples per ID per 'follow-up' year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  mutate(across(contains('date'), ~ as_date(.x)),
         months_passed = interval(baseline_date, date) %/% months(1),
         #### to group by years instead of grouping by multiples of 12 months:
         ## years_passed = interval(baseline_date, date) %/% years(1)
         ) |>
  count(ID, sample, months_passed)


## + # A tibble: 4 x 4
##   ID    sample  months_passed     n
##   <chr> <chr>           <dbl> <int>
## 1 PD1   sample1             0     1
## 2 PD1   sample2             0     1
## 3 PD2   sample1             0     1
## 4 PD2   sample2            16     1
```

(not sure from your question which dates have to be compared for the desired duration, adapt as fit)

Comment: That make the trick exactly as desired, I've just added 'group_by(years_passed) %>%
  summarise(mean_per_year = mean(n, na.rm=T))' at the end to get the mean number of samples within a year (per ID).